# Suppose the matrices $ A,B $ have integer eigenvalues. When is $ Tr(AB) $ an integer?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A,B $ be $ n \times n $ complex matrices with integer eigenvalues. What are some conditions that guarantee $ Tr(AB) $ is an integer? For example what if $ B $ is a projector (self adjoint and $ B^2=B $)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable and commutes (namely $AB=BA$), and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are integers, then the eigenvalues of $AB$ are an integer too. This simply follows because there exists a common basis of eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$. In other words it could exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that

$$A=M^{-1}D_1M \quad \text{and} \quad B=M^{-1}D_2M$$

where $D_i$ are diagonal matrices. The entries on the principal diagonal of $D_1$ and $D_2$ are therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Moreover

$$AB=M^{-1}D_1D_2M.$$

Therefore $AB$ is diagonalisable and its eigenvalues are integers. In particular, $Tr(AB)=Tr(D_1D_2)\in \mathbb N$.

Can this help you?